# Skip step of verification database when i lunch composer install in my job jenkins

Tags: php, jenkins, composer-php

I have a jenkins job for a symfony project. Every time I run the command composer install if it does not find the database it crashes.

I would like to know if there is any way to ingest the database verification step.

Comment: What database verification step do you refer to? Can you please show the error that you are running into?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the execution of all scripts defined in `composer.json` file. I think database verification defined there.

Just use `composer install --no-scripts`

Answer (score 0):

To skip the database verification just by adding this line in **config.yml** file, exactly in the **doctrine configuration** block :

```
server_version: '5.6'
```